# Insert new line before multiple keywords in text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following text:

"This is the problem. Extract some data from this document.
Text is what I am looking for. Not really happening"

I am able to insert a new line after multiple keywords:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input('text.txt', inplace=1):
    print line,
    if line.startswith(('Extract',  'Text')):
        print ' '
```

But I cannot find a solution for also adding a newline before the keywords.

Final format should look like:

"This is the problem.

Extract some data from this document.

Text is what I am looking for. Not really happening"

The issue is that all words can change but the keywords. I am looking for editing any text containing the keywords.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: ...what? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: this might give an explanation about print and the using of a comma: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18179618/4019425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input('text.txt', inplace=1):
    if line.startswith(('Extract',  'Text')):
        print '\n'+line+'\n'    
    else:    
        print line
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The regex sub function would get you what you want:

```
import re
keywords_regex = r"(Extract )|(Text )"
line = re.sub(keywords_regex, "\n\1", line) + "\n"
```

But first you'll have to split your input text into its respective sentences. You could do that this way:

```
import re
lines = text.split(". ")

# replace the removed periods
lines = [line + "." for line in lines]

keywords_regex = r"(Extract )|(Text )"
lines = [re.sub(keywords_regex, "\n\1", line) + "\n" for line in lines]
```

"\1" is regex shorthand "the first matched group."

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution.