# How to print twice on the same line using functions

Tags: function, python-3.x

```
def Drawstars(spaces, stars):
          spaces = int(spaces) - 1
          stars = int(stars)
          print(line = " " * spaces + "*" *stars)

# i want this to be printed once
s = 3
st = 3
Drawstars(s, st)

#i want these to be printed twice

s = 3
st = 1
Drawstars(s, st)

s= 2
st = 2
Drawstars(s, st)
```

How would I the bottom two to work twice on the same line and the top one only once.
what i get is:

```
   *
   *
   **
```

but i want is:

```
   *
   * **
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New line in python print() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179606/new-line-in-python-print-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the function `sys.stdout.write()` it can print without adding a new line afterwards.

If you had a function like this

```
def DrawstarsOneline(spaces, stars):
      spaces = int(spaces) - 1
      stars = int(stars)
      sys.stdout.write(" " * spaces + "*" *stars)
```

Then you could call your code like this

```
s = 3
st = 1
DrawstarsOneline(s, st)

s= 2
st = 2
Drawstars(s, st)
```

And it would produce the desired output.

**You would need to import the SYS module at the top of your code with this line:**
`import sys`