# How do I create a horizontal multiplication table in Python?

Tags: python, multiplication

So far I have tried to create a table of the first `6` multiples of `2` that should give:

```
2  4  6  8  10  12
```

My code for this currently looks like:

```
i = 1
while i <= 6:
   print(2*i ,' \t' , )
   i = i + 1
```

But this `outputs` them `vertically`, not `horizontally` so:

```
2   
4   
6   
8   
10      
12
```

There is also a `tab` after each `number`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New line in python print() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179606/new-line-in-python-print-function)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `for-loop` as they are more Pythonic for this application than `while` loops.

So just `loop` through the numbers between `1` and `6` and `print` that `number` `multiplied` by `2` with a space instead of the `new-line` character. Finally, you can call one more `print` at the end to move to the next line after they have all been printed.

```
for i in range(1, 7):
    print(i * 2, end=' ')

print()
```

which `outputs`:

```
2 4 6 8 10 12
```

---

If you wanted do this whole thing in one-line, you could use a `generator` and `string.join()`. You may not fully understand this, but the following produces the same result:

```
print(" ".join(str(i*2) for i in range(1, 7)))
```

which gives:

```
2 4 6 8 10 12
```

---

Note that one last thing is that this method doesn't produce a uniformly spaced table. To show what I mean by "uniformly spaced", here are some examples:

**not uniformly spaced:**

```
1234  1 123 12 12312 123
```

**uniformly spaced:**

```
1234  1     123   12    12312 123
```

To make the output `print` nicely like above, we can use `.ljust`:

```
print("".join(str(i*2).ljust(3) for i in range(1, 7)))
```

which gives a nicer table:

```
2  4  6  8  10 12
```

---

Finally, if you wanted to make this into a `function` that is more general purpose, you could do:

```
def tbl(num, amnt):
    print("".join(str(i*num).rjust(len(str(num*amnt))+1) for i in range(1,amnt+1)))
```

and some examples of this `function`:

```
>>> tbl(3, 10)
  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
>>> tbl(9, 5)
  9 18 27 36 45
>>> tbl(10, 10)
  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your print statement to be like this: `print(2*i, end=' \t')`  The `end` key argument sets what the ending character should be.  By default, it's a newline, as you know.